# Deleting and Formatting partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 14.04

So, I just deleted the XP partition on my hard-drive, and now have 30 Gb of extra space. But that space isnt being used by my Ubuntu file-system, and I'm getting warnings that there is only about 200 Mb of space left, even though I have the empty 300 gb partition

So, my question is how do I connect the two partitions and allow Ubuntu to use the 30gb?

Comment: The possible duplicate didn't help with my problem.

Comment: Can you give some screen shots of your partitions in Gparted